# Base class observable(variable) remains undefined in spec file - Angular unit testing

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jestjs, jasmine

I have a componentA that inherits(extends) another one i.e componentB. The problem is unit tests of componentA are breaking because an observable defined in componentB remains undefined in spec.ts.

Relevant part of ComponentB(Base class)

`this.storeObservable = this.store.select(selectCandidateState);`

Accessing this in ComponentA,

```
this.storeObservable.subscribe((candidateState) => {
   this.candidateSkills = candidateState.skills;
   this.unsavedChanges = false;
  });
```

Now the unit test of componentA are breaking with this message:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined,

while pointing to `this.storeObservable.subscribe`

ComponentA

```
export class ComponentA extends ComponentB implements OnInit, OnDestroy 
ngOnInit() {
     super.ngOnInit();

this.storeObservable.subscribe((candidateState) => {
  this.candidateSkills = candidateState.skills;
  this.unsavedChanges = false;
});
```

The unit tests

```
    let shallow: Shallow<ComponentA>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    const actions$ = new Observable();
    const services = [Store];
    const mockedServices = [ConfigCzarServiceMock({ test: 'property' })];
    shallow = createShallowComponent(
      ComponentA,
      ProfileModule,
      [componentB],
      [],
      services,
      mockedServices,
     );


> All the tests break with above error. TypeError: Cannot read property
> 'subscribe' of undefined,
```

Comment: It sounds like the issue is that the storeObservable property is not being properly initialized in the child component (ComponentA) when it is being accessed. This could be because the parent component (ComponentB) is not properly passing down the store property or the selectCandidateState function to the child component.

One solution could be to make sure that the store property and the selectCandidateState function are being passed down as inputs to the child component, and that the child component is properly initializing the storeObservable property in its constructor.

Comment: @onetwo12 The functionality is working fine. Although the tests are breaking

Comment: I don't think the author is talking about a parent/child relation here, but rather is trying to extend a class (inheritance). @ABGR would be great if you can include a little bit more core (class definition) in order to receive helpful feedback.